# Automate Transform Process(Header Issue)

Tags: excel, python-3.x

Raw Format Example:
[image: Raw Format Example]

Finished format:
[image: Finished format]

I am attempting to come up with a way to reformat multiple excel documents into a format that easier to perform analysis on. I have identified how to manually perform the process but coding it in python has me bewildered.

Recording a VBA macro

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/56876288/edit) to clarify what you are trying to accomplish, what you have tried so far and what the exact problem is?

Comment: It's really going to depend on what you mean by "a format that easier to perform analysis on". What format? Easier how? What analysis?

Comment: Reformatting data is a prime task for Excel Power Query (aka Get and Transform data).  Reformat it once and then it can easily be replicated.

Comment: The pictures I posted were of the original format and the second picture was of the format I was looking for. Essentially I want to transpose the header information which would require me to insert 5 columns and transpose the headers into those columns. I'll see if I can get my Excel version upgraded and try to use Power Query @Jenn

Comment: @JAE What version of Excel do you have now?

Comment: @JAE It comes included with Excel 2016 and up. If you have 2010 or 2013 you can download it as an add-in. https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=39379&CorrelationId=f1925123-1318-41e1-b175-e3ad5f3a9f80

Comment: I now have Excel 2016, at my time of posting Excel 2007 was installed on my unit, I got everything set up but I'm still not sure power query will be the answer due to the complexity of the transformation. I can UNPIVOT the data in its original form if I manually go in and deleted all the information except the "plan number" and make that a heading. But that's still relatively problematic as I'd have to go into each worksheet monthly and manually handle that part of the transformation.

Comment: I finally figured it out. I needed to Transpose, then select the first 4 columns and Unpivot the others! @Jenn